# Qt Quick emulation layer crashed when QtQuick.Controls is imported in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2, qt-quick

My ssd died and I had to reinstall Qt, Im using the same version as before (5.15.2, Qt Creator 6.0.2 and MSVC2019). Described problems appears only while using Static build.

- *This type (ApplicationWindow) is not supported as a root* (Im not 100% sure if it was fine before reinstall)
- *Invalid property name "title, maximumHeight, maximumWidth, minimumHeight, minimumWidth"*.
- And finally after resolving (Changed from `ApplicationWindow` to `Window`, and commented Invalid Properties) these two errors I got: *Line 1: Qt Quick emulation layer crashed*. I attached a debugger to Qt Creator and it's 0xC0000005 on Editor, Preview and Render.

I tested it in both ways, with latest Qt Creator (installed before making Static kit because it will wipe my Qt directory) and with Qt Creator 6.0.2 (installed after making Static kit).
To compile Static Kit I used [this](https://github.com/fpoussin/Qt5-MSVC-Static) script, but after some problems (`jom` and `jom install` did not create any files in `QtInstallDir`) I just run `configure.bat` by myself, and then `jom` and `jom install` and files were in their place.

The solution can be:

- Designing using diffrent kit with `Window` and then on release change Kit to static, change `Window` to `ApplicationWindow` (Im using onClosing from `ApplicationWindow`).

but it's dirty and I personally do not like it. Is there any other solution?

EDIT: non-static versions are fine (self-compiled and one from MaintenanceTool).

Static configure.bat:

```
configure.bat -prefix %QTINSTALLDIR% -platform %PLATFORM% -opensource -debug-and-release -confirm-license -opengl dynamic -mp -static -static-runtime -no-shared -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -no-compile-examples -nomake examples -no-icu -optimize-size -qt-sqlite -openssl-linked OPENSSL_PREFIX=%SSLINSTALLDIR%
```

Non-static configure.bat:

```
configure.bat -prefix %QTINSTALLDIR% -platform %PLATFORM% -opensource -debug-and-release -confirm-license -opengl dynamic -mp -no-compile-examples -nomake examples -optimize-size -qt-sqlite
```

Diffrence:

```
-static -static-runtime -no-shared -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -openssl-linked OPENSSL_PREFIX=<location>
```

Comment: Are you sure your static build of Qt is otherwise identical to the non-static version you're using?

Comment: @mzimmers To be honest I'm not sure how to compare them, but I guess it's related to configure.bat settings? 

I will edit main post and I will include my configure.bat settings.

Comment: I don't see anything in your script parameters that look like they should cause a problem. I suggest you look at this link and consider modifying your program. Without seeing configure.bat, I can't say for sure, but I'm wondering whether you're using different versions of the Qt source.

Comment: What does "different versions of the Qt source" mean? Diffrent than before reinstall or diffrent than original in script under link? It's the same version (of course if 5.15.2 equals 5.15.2 lol) as before reinstall and in the script 5.15.2 is the default version. In the script I changed from -release to -debug-and-release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed the `Invalid property name ..`, I dont know what really fixed it but:

- I had wrong versions of requirements. I was on latest of Ruby, Python etc.
- I installed Submodules one more time using script linked in main post and then installed them one by one by my own hands using `qmake` then `jom clean all` then `jom install`.

Also I found that the `Line 1: Qt Quick emulation layer crashed.` error appear only when I have `QtQuick.Controls <any_version>` in imports. Im still trying to fix this.

**Fixed. I did this by doing those steps:**

- In maintenance tool I downloaded Mingw64 and Mingw64 for 5.15.2 and for "Tools".
- I did an static mingw build using this powershell script: https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW
- I saw that the script is changing `qmake.conf` files in `mkspecs` folder. I ran [this](https://github.com/fpoussin/Qt5-MSVC-Static) MSVC script to make MSVC Static build and after unzipping QtBase I modified `qmake.conf` in `mkspecs/winrt-x64-msvc2019` and in `mkspecs/win32-msvc`.

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -Os
DEFINES += QT_STATIC_BUILD
```

- Then the `qt setup` and `qt build` command, when build is finished I modified the **(THIS TIME IN PREFIX LOCATION / LOCATION WHERE QT STATIC IS INSTALLED)** `qmake.conf` in `mkspecs/winrt-x64-msvc2019` and in `mkspecs/win32-msvc`

```
CONFIG += static
```

- Run Qt Creator and the Designer is fine.